# Why do bacteria denitrify?

Tags: biochemistry, bacteriology, nitrogen-cycle

Denitrification is the microbial respiration in anoxic condition. If the process is complete we have :

$$2 \text{NO}_3^{-} + 10 \text{e}^{-} +12\text{H}^+ \rightarrow \text{N}_2 + 6 \text{H}_2\text{O}$$

In this series of reactions, nitrate and hydrogen are transformed into nitrogen and water with bacteria's energy. All the elements are given back to the environment. So why do bacteria denitrify? What do they take for themselves in this process?

Comment: The same thing they get from aerobic respiration, just less of it.

Comment: Need water? Need to lower pH? Remove excess nitrogen to something relatively inert?  These questions might serve to hypothesize about the 'biological function' that this chemical reaction serves in the metabolism of an organism.

Comment: nitrate is energy you can even use it to make explosives so it contains a lot of energy for bacterial growth.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. One of the things we ask people who ask questions to do is to [research](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) their question themselves before posting, and tell us what they found and how it was insufficient for their purposes. One obvious resource is [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denitrifying_bacteria) which gave me the answer. Did you try that and understand the page? You say that this process **uses** energy — but that is not correct. Have you learned about energy generation in living organisms?

Comment: I said 'lower pH' above, but rather it would be 'raise the pH'. I meant lower the hydronium concentration rather than lower the pH.

Comment: On the topic of energy, ["*Denitrifying bacteria use denitrification to generate ATP.*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denitrifying_bacteria#Denitrification_mechanism) is suggestive.

Comment: Notice that the reverse process, [biological nitrogen fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_fixation#Biological), requires lots of energy.